# jQuery Even Height Floated LI's

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists, each

I have a list as follows:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li>lorem</li>
   <li>lorem</li>
   <li class="last">lorem</li>
   <li>lorem</li>
   <li>lorem</li>
   <li class="last">lorem</li>
</ul>
```

I have the li floated to the left in rows of 3. How can I use jQuery to select each row (3 li's) find the max height in that row then set the others in that row to the same height?

This is what I have now, but it only looks at the li's as a whole, not as individual rows.

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('ul#list li').each(function() {
   maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
}).height(maxHeight);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the elements up into rows first, then user your logic on each row individually:

```
var items = $('ul#list li');
var total = items.length;

for(i = 0; i < total; i+=3){
    var row = items.slice(i, Math.min(i + 2, total - 1));
    var maxHeight = 0;
    row.each(function() {
        maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
    }).height(maxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the container to `overflow: hidden`, you can do this without JavaScript, by using a very large `padding-bottom` and an equally large negative `margin-bottom` (and to preserve a visual padding on the bottom, move the `margin-bottom` closer to `0` to compensate). Example:

```
#list {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#list li {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
var getMaxHeight = function ($elms) {
    var maxH = 0;
    $elms.each(function () {
        if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxH) {
            maxH = $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });
    return maxH;
};

var $li = $('#list li');
$li.height(getMaxHeight($li)); // Put this on load or doc.ready
```

Comment: I think op is asking how to resize items in each row relative the other items in the row, not the entire set.

Comment: Yes, is what I am asking. The code I posted in the questions does the exact same thing as this. I am looking for something that will work on a per row basis.

Answer (score -1):

May this code helps you...

```
$("#list li:nth-child(3n)").each(function(){
   var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, $(this).children().map(function(){ return $(this).outerHeight(); }).get());
   $(this).children().each(function(){
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
});
```